# I can't build project with quickfix

Tags: c++, quickfix, microsoft-runtime-library

I tri build project with quickfix.lib
In VC++ Directories i set path "lib"
In C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Dir I set path to my inlude files "include"
In Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies I add quickfix.lib
This project build correct, but when I use Object from FIX, I see
**Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2038 mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in FIXExchangeAPI.obj SampleGateway C:...\quickfix.lib(Dictionary.obj) 1**

What must I do?
I changed RuntimeLibrary to each value and compile, but it not helped me

Comment: You are mixing debug and release. Thankfully the compiler complains. If it did not you would have undefined behavior. You need to use a release library for the release configuration and a debug library for the debug configuration.

Comment: Now I used Released x64 Configuration, but I have same error:Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2038 mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in FIXExchangeAPI.obj SampleGateway C:\...\quickfix.lib(SessionSettings.obj)

Comment: That is still a mismatch but a slightly different error and fixable by setting your release CRT of your project to dynamic instead of static runtime.

Comment: Ok< thanks you, a Really build quickfixd.lib and set RuntimeLibrary Debug Dll(MDd) and it works, and build quickfix.lib with parametr RintimeLibrary Dll(MD) and it work very well!!!

Comment: That is correct. The basic idea is your runtime you use for your code must be the same as the runtime used for all of its c++ dependencies.